# How to switch dynamic transactions with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture, spring-transactions

First, thank you very much for reading me.

I have a web application with the following architecture:

```
WEB <-> ManagedBean (JSF) <-> Service <-> DAO
                                               -> DataBase 1
                                               -> DataBase 2
                                               -> DataBase n
```

All above surrounded with Spring FrameWork and "@Transaction" annotation in the interface of the Service, in example:

```
@Transactional("myDataSource")
public void doCommit( MyObject object );
```

**Is it possible to change dynamically the DataBase connection?** The schemas are exactly the same, but **I need** (depending on a parameter on the ManagedBean) **to use different transaction managers**.

I put an interceptor on DAO and read an hibernate file, launch the selects and it works, but in a Transactional context is not possible because Spring do the commit in the transaction that it creates.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: SUPPORTS does not start transaction, any idea where transaction is started?

Comment: I can add a final parameter to the Transactional annotation that indicates the dataSource, but I need to do it dynamically.

Comment: If it was straight possible, I'd put it in my answer. Another option is to use N service layer bean instances, each bound to a different datasource, and dynamically route to them with a routing implementation of service. Might be problematic if you have your service layer split in a lot of classes.

Comment: Yes, is what I have done yesterday; I have defined a personal Spring Scope for the differents dataSources and, instead of having only one Instance of the Service Class, I have 1 instance for every dataSource, but now I need to load the new Service with the new dataSource configuration, by XML or with try-catch blocks. What do you think? :)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code but since there is no standard preferred solution you can go with whatever works for you.

Comment: mrembisz, thank you, it has been a productive conversation with you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change dynamically the DataBase connection?

If you using transactional annotations, the only way would be to alter the datasource definition (in your app context).  But no you can not do it programmatically in java alone without changing the transaction implementation.

Comment: So... I must to write my own Transaction annotation that allows variables, Isn´t it?

Comment: no, you can't change an annotation at runtime. You must use somethign other than transactional annotation, like @mrembisz said. Or change the datasource definition (which I assume is in your app context).

Comment: NimChimpsky, thanks you very much. I understand that I have 2 choices: 1. remove the annotations and do it by XML configuration creating the XML dinamically or 2. remove the annotations and do the transactions by try-catch blocks.